# Spring CAS Sample application

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, cas

Any one can share me the sample applications with Spring CAS authentication (both client and server configuration). Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [Spring Security CAS Sample service](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/sample-apps.html#cas-sample) and CAS Server included in the Spring Security distribution. The [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/cas.html) discusses what is involved to set each aspect up.

### Running With Gradle

The easiest way to run them both is to install a git client and perform

`git clone https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security`

Then you can run

```
./gradlew cas
```

At that point you should be able to open

https://localhost:8443/cas-sample/

Then you can login with the username password rod/rod

### Running in Spring Tool Suite

You can also run it using Spring Tool Suite. For detailed instructions see [Running Spring Security's Tutorial Sample in Spring Tool Suite](http://rwinch.blogspot.com/2011/03/running-spring-securitys-tutorial.html) to get the basic project setup. Next, you will need to follow the special instructions in [Running Spring Security's CAS and PreAuth Samples in STS](http://rwinch.blogspot.com/2011/04/running-spring-securitys-cas-and.html) to get the CAS application to properly work.